# SQL Server retrieving data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 I have two tables:

```
Table A
1
2
3

Table B
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Is there a simple (not using cursors) way to select:

```
1, A
1, B
2, C
2, D
3, E
3, F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution (not mine, but is better/simpler) is:

```
DECLARE @TotalTableA INT
SET @TotalTableA = (SELECT COUNT(Company_ID) FROM @TableA AS c)

;WITH cte1 AS (
 SELECT Company_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Company_ID) AS row_num
 FROM @TableA AS c
),cte2 (Person_ID, row_num) as
(
 SELECT Person_ID, (Person_ID % @TotalTableA) + 1 AS row_num
 FROM @TableB
)

SELECT Company_ID,Person_ID FROM cte1 JOIN cte2 ON cte2.row_num = cte1.row_num
```

This avoids counters and does not need the ID fields. A slight difference is my first idea was strict about two rows from TableB. This answer tries to evenly split all the rows in TableB between TableA.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt was to not try anything too fancy. It goes something like this:

```
SET @maxcounter = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @TableA)
SET @counter = 1
WHILE(@counter <= @maxcounter)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        (SELECT Company_ID FROM @TableA WHERE ID = @counter),
        (SELECT Person_ID FROM @TableB WHERE ID = (@counter * 2) - 1)

    SELECT
        (SELECT Company_ID FROM @TableA WHERE ID = @counter),
        (SELECT Person_ID FROM @TableB WHERE ID = (@counter * 2))

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

maxcounter and counter are int variables. TableA and TableB are table variables, and both have an ID identity field. It's not elegant, but it does what I want it do to.

This isn't going into production - it's just being used in a script to populate tables with test data.